# java class does not recognize the jar file im going to import

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I downloaded `a.jar` into `work space/project name/lib`. I am able to add it in the build path. But the problem i met is that i can not import this jar file into a class.  :(

Say the jar file i have is `a.jar`. i am going to use the `main` method from this jar file to do some actions. But i can not import this `a.jar` because it does not recognize the jar file's name.

How can i achieve that? Or is there a better way to do that?

normally i use command line to run the jar file. now i want to automate it from the code. Please help me if u can.

Thank you

Comment: really can't understand your question.

Comment: What is cmdline and classpath and where is a.jar

Comment: I copy this jar file under work space/project name/lib. and add into my project.

Comment: Is there a `main` method within a class packaged in your `a.jar` or you separately want to create a class with a `main` method and use the `a.jar` file?

Comment: basically there is a jar file and i can not use it because i dont know how to import into a class.

Comment: You don't import jar files into a class... You have to import specific classes which are in the jar file...

Comment: yes. i want to call the a.jar.main method from my main method.

Comment: ya, that is my problem. i dont know method name from that jar file. only want to call the main method in the jar file.

Comment: Use Java Decompiler from "http://jd.benow.ca/" to decompile the jar and find packages and classes. At least, you will be able determine the package to search for method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `jar` doesn't contain a `main` method. It is nothing else like a ZIP archive.

A *executable* JAR has a `Main-Class` (full qualified class name) with a `main` method defined in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Main-Class: my.company.MainClass
```

If you like to call the `main` method of the `Main-Class` add this JAR file on Java classpath. Add the `main` call in your code like:

```
...
import my.company
...
public void yourMethodWithMainCall() {
 // my.company.MainClass is defined as 'Main-Class' in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF of a.jar
 MainClass.main(...);
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JAR file is Java archive. If you open it with archive manger of your OS look for `META-INF` directory and `MANIFEST.MF` file, it is text file. It contains info about main class which you can run. For example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_25-b17 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: javaapplication1.JavaApplication1
```